# Is it possible to use typescript function overloads AND forwardRef?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, overloading, react-forwardref

Simplified example code:

```js
interface IInputElementStringProps {
  value: string;
}
interface IInputElementNumberProps {
  value: number;
}

function InputElement(props: IInputElementStringProps);
function InputElement(props: IInputElementNumberProps);
function InputElement(props: IInputElementStringProps | IInputElementNumberProps) {
  // Implementing code that returns a JSX.Element.
}
```

How can I make this use forwardRef to pass in a ref, but keep my overloads?

Example without overloads

```js
const InputElement = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, IInputElementStringProps | IInputElementNumberProps>((props, ref) => {
  // Implementing code that returns a JSX.Element with a ref.
});
```

Comment: First: I'm not positive about this, but I think that the interface declaration implemented by the first argument to `forwardRef` might be preventing overloads. See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e5d751123d79dcdcc270ec795437c2495179a0d9/types/react/index.d.ts#L566-L579

Comment: Second: Your example doesn't illustrate why a simple union of prop types is a non-solution compared to an overload. Can you update your example to show why that won't work for your case?

Comment: @jsejcksn "I think that the interface declaration implemented by the first argument to forwardRef might be preventing overloads"
That is incorrect. The first argument defines the type of the ref.
As for why not use a union? Essentially (I believe) an overload presents cleaner in a UI like VSCode.